# Weird get_cpu()/put_cpu() call

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I ran into a weird chunk of code in a driver I am maintaining and I can't explain what it does or why it exists:

```
internal_driver_struct->prev_cpu = get_cpu();
put_cpu();
```

Basically there's an internal structure that keeps track of the return of `get_cpu()`, but this value is never checked ever again.

Is it safe to assume that this is a bug or vestigial code?  What (if any) side effects are there from calling `get_cpu()` followed immediately by `put_cpu()`?  Note that this code is reached from the driver's implementation of `read()` (i.e., the user context).

Comment: What I usually do is comment it out, make a note in my log and retest.  If it still works, fine.  If, at some time in the future, there is some inexplicable problem, you have your note to remind you to try uncommenting it.  Like you say, it's probably old debug code that got left in.

Comment: Yea, that's my current approach as well, since science hasn't given us time travel yet to go back and figure out what the original developer was thinking.  I was just wondering if there's anything I'm missing, because to me it looks like that code isn't doing anything.

Comment: In driver code `get` increments a reference count and `put` decrements it.

Comment: @stark, so since these two operations are happening one right after another, the net effect is nothing happens?  Am I missing something?

Comment: `get_cpu` calls `preempt_disable` and `put_cpu` calls `preempt_enable` so there are some execution barriers.

Comment: So there is an execution barrier between the two lines of code?  The net effect should be nothing, no?

Comment: Looks like a dead code. Side effect of it would be a barrier, which might sync write buffers and caches in CPU. Such code requires very deep knowledge of the code context to understand intentions.